# video streaming and processing by html5

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, audio-streaming, live-streaming

can HTML5 process streaming video ?

I mean , is there any way to create HTML page to handle the streaming and processing the video which is received from TV .

I know HTML5 can accept CAM as video input , but i have no idea if HTML5 can support video card or any video streaming device ?

thank you .

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with HTML5 directly... if the browser supports reading from video devices other than cameras, then these devices are accepted.

On many systems, a video device is a video device.  On Windows this isn't always the case.  There are several video capture APIs and not all devices are available on all APIs.  Fortunately, there is software available that tends to make more devices available, such as [SplitCam](http://splitcamera.com/).